# Проблема с получением данных OKHTTP3

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var recyclerviewDetails: RecyclerView
    var arrayListDetails: ArrayList<News> = ArrayList();
    private val client = OkHttpClient()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerviewDetails = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNews)
        run("https://188.40.167.45:3001")

    }

    private fun run(url: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    throw IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                } else {
                val strResponse = response.body!!.string()
                val jsonContact: JSONObject = JSONObject(strResponse)
                val size: Int = 5
                arrayListDetails = ArrayList()
                for (i in 0 until size) {
                    val jsonObjectDetail: JSONObject = jsonContact
                    val news: News = News()
                    news.title = jsonObjectDetail.getString("title")
                    news.type = jsonObjectDetail.getString("type")
                    news.img = jsonObjectDetail.getString("img")
                    news.clickUrl = jsonObjectDetail.getString("click_url")
                    news.time = jsonObjectDetail.getString("time")
                    news.top = jsonObjectDetail.getString("top")
                    arrayListDetails.add(news)
                    runOnUiThread{
                        val adapter: Adapter = Adapter()
                        recyclerviewDetails.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.newsapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.demo.newsapp.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Вот ошибки в логе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в Postman запросил свой url http://188.40.167.45:3001 , и все получил данные, но при этом в приложении, http://188.40.167.45:3001 крашится, а https://188.40.167.45:3001 просто запускается без соединения

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa загляните сюда, похоже на Ваш случай

Comment: да вообще такой бред, я не хотел ретрофитом пользоваться здесь, потому что проект безумно легкий, думал OKHTTP проще, а тут мне ssl безопасность решать? я начинающий программист, жестко...

Comment: Вот поэтому все и используют ретрофит)))

Comment: можете помочь как быстренько свапнуть всё в ретрофит?)

Comment: Гляньте вот эту статью http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/retrofit.php на мой взгляд, там вполне достаточный материал

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: А на какой версии ОС запускаете? На некоторых девайсах с 4 версией могут быть проблемы с `https` соединением, которые можно вылечить в пару строк кода, если на девайсе есть гугловые сервисы. Также, по идее, `https` для IP адреса не должно работать, только для доменного имени. Ну и логи надо текстом выкладывать, на картинке почти ничего не разобрать.

Comment: так я текстом и пытался мне написали что похоже на спам...

Comment: версия android 10 api 29 c гугл сервисами